# how to replace an entire column on Pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to replace an entire column on a Pandas DataFrame with another column taken from another DataFrame, an example will clarify what I am looking for

```
import pandas as pd
dic = {'A': [1, 4, 1, 4], 'B': [9, 2, 5, 3], 'C': [0, 0, 5, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

df is

```
'A' 'B' 'C'
 1   9   0
 4   2   0
 1   5   5
 4   3   3
```

Now I have another dataframe called `df1` with a column `"E"` that is

```
df1['E'] = [ 4, 4, 4, 0]
```

and I would like to replace column `"B"` of df with column `"E"` of `df1`

```
'A' 'E' 'C'
 1   4   0
 4   4   0
 1   4   5
 4   0   3
```

I tried to use the `.replace()` method in many ways but I didn't get anything good. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do:

```py
df.B = df1.E
```

That's all!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 109):

If the indices match then:

```
df['B'] = df1['E']
```

should work otherwise:

```
df['B'] = df1['E'].values
```

will work so long as the length of the elements matches

Comment: I had the same issue and this method worked for me. 
df['B'] = df1['E'].values
Can someone explain the reason why this one worked vs the other one did np

Comment: I get the following warning with this method: `SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.`

Answer (score 47):

If you don't mind getting a new data frame object returned as opposed to updating the original [Pandas .assign()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) will avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning`. Your example:

```
df = df.assign(B=df1['E'])
```

Comment: Let me extend this answer to replacing multiple columns at once. This can be achieved with: `df = df.assign(**df1.to_dict(orient='series'))` :)

Comment: This answer assumes that the name of the column to be updated is always a valid Python variable name, which won't be the case in general. But, more generally it can be passed by constructing a dictionary `df = df.assign(**{'columnname':newvalues})`

Comment: @MRule Thank you very much! I had this exact problem and your solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 10):

For those that struggle with the "SettingWithCopy" warning, here's a workaround which may not be so efficient, but still gets the job done.

Suppose you with to overwrite column_1 and column_3, but retain column_2 and column_4

```
columns_to_overwrite = ["column_1", "column_3"]
```

First delete the columns that you intend to replace...

```
original_df.drop(labels=columns_to_overwrite, axis="columns", inplace=True)
```

... then re-insert the columns, but using the values that you intended to overwrite

```
original_df[columns_to_overwrite] = other_data_frame[columns_to_overwrite]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html):

```
In [7]: df.eval('B = @df1.E', inplace=True)

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  4  0
1  4  4  0
2  1  4  5
3  4  0  3
```

Since `inplace=True` you don't need to assign it back to `df`.