# Python 3 - Mapping list within Pandas Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to replace a list of existing values within a pandas column.

```
   team ID ... win
0     1 ...   8
1     1 ...   4
2     3 ...   5
3     4 ...   2
4     5 ...   1
```

(team IDs can repeat and are not unique)

I'm looking to change the team ID to team names from an existing list that I already have

```
team_names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

I was previously doing it like this:

```
df.name = df.name.replace({
    1: 'A',
    2: 'B',
    3: 'C',
    4: 'D'
})
```

However, the issue i'm facing now is that the two lists I want to map between is almost 100. So I was wondering if anyone could share a faster method of doing this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846060/how-to-replace-an-entire-column-on-pandas-dataframe Is this what you're looking to do?

Comment: So do you just want `['A', 'B', 'C', ....., 'AA', 'AB', 'AC']`?

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` the two lists and then pass the result to a dict:

```
df.element_type = df.element_type.replace(dict(zip(list1, list2)))
```

`zip` works like this:

```
>>> dict(zip([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]))
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

## EDIT

If the order of the team names in your list corresponds with the ids (`1-> "A", 2 -> "B", etc.`), then this works:

```
df["team ID"] = df["team ID"].replace(dict(zip(
    df["team ID"].sort_values().unique(),
    team_names
)))
```

Comment: What if I were trying to replace the existing list within the columns itself?

df.element_type = df.element_type.replace(dict(zip([df.element_type.unique], [A, B, C, D])))

Comment: What existing list? Please edit your question to indicate your example input data and your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is inspired by this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29351603/8146556), and can be adapted to address your question. You can use `itertools.product()` with `string.ascii_uppercase` to create a list of letters like `['A', 'B', 'C', ....., 'AA', 'AB', 'AC']` with the same length as your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import string
import itertools

newlist = []

def iter_all_strings():
    for size in itertools.count(1):
        for s in itertools.product(string.ascii_uppercase, repeat=size):
            yield "".join(s)

for s in itertools.islice(iter_all_strings(), len(df)):
    newlist.append(s)

df['team ID'] = newlist
```

Yields:

```
  team ID  win
0       A    8
1       B    4
2       C    5
3       D    2
4       E    1
```

I see that you modified your input dataframe to include non-unique values in the `team ID` column after I composed my answer, so a slight modification to the last statement will produce the desired result (note @Edgar R. Mondragón posted this part first in his answer):

```
df['team ID'] = df["team ID"].replace(dict(zip(
    df["team ID"].sort_values().unique(),
    newlist
)))
```

Yields:

```
  team ID  win
0       A    8
1       A    4
2       B    5
3       C    2
4       D    1
```

Answer (score 0):

If indeed you just want to replace the ID with the corresponding name:

Create the translation dictionary:

```
dict= {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'D', 5: 'E'}
```

Then replace with the corresponding values:

```
df['team_ID'] = pd.Series([dict[i] for i in list(df.team_ID) if i in list(df.team_ID)])
```

Gives:

```
     team_ID  win
0       A    8
1       A    4
2       C    5
3       D    2
4       E    1
```

Answer (score 0):

if the position of each team name within your team_names list corresponds to the team_id you can do:

```
{i[0]:i[1] for i in enumerate(team_names)}
```

> {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D'}

Replace the manual dictionary with the dict comprehension above:

```
df.name = df.name.replace({i[0]:i[1] for i in enumerate(team_names)})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_dict= {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'D', 5: 'E'}
df['team Id']=df['team Id'].map(my_dict)
```